# ready-function togglePanel() not working

Tags: function, polymer

I have this code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<core-drawer-panel>
    <core-header-panel drawer id="section-drawer">
        <div id="logo-container">LOGO</div>
    </core-header-panel>
    <core-header-panel main id="section-main">
        <core-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" id="navicon"></paper-icon-button>
            <div class="page-title">TITLE</div>
        </core-toolbar>
    </core-header-panel>
</core-drawer-panel>
<script>
    function standardPolymerLoad() {
        setMenuAction();
    }

    function setMenuAction() {
        var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
        drawerPanel = document.getElementById('section-drawer');
        navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
            drawerPanel.togglePanel();
        });
    }

    document.addEventListener("polymer-ready", standardPolymerLoad);
</script>
```

But when i click on a paper-icon-button, chrome show this error:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

refers to this function: drawerPanel.togglePanel();

Can you help me?

Comment: Place jquery library before webcomponent.js

Comment: @ShuhaibV
I tried to move it before webcomponent.js but still does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My stupid mistake.
The element on which to call togglePanel() must be core-drawer-panel, not the drawer element.

```
<core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">
    <core-header-panel drawer id="gw-section-drawer">
        <div id="logoContainer">LOGO</div>
    </core-header-panel>
    <core-header-panel main id="sectionMain">
        <core-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" id="navicon"></paper-icon-button>
            <div class="pageTitle">TITLE</div>
        </core-toolbar>
    </core-header-panel>
</core-drawer-panel>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("polymer-ready", function() {
        document.getElementById('navicon').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('drawerPanel').togglePanel();
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Giuseppe is correct, remember we using toggle and want to call the full core-drawer-panel, putting the id on the core-header-panel wont work as it's not the full drawer but its looking to toggle the actual header only.